# How do I extract a specific file from a tar archive?

Tags: command-line, files, backup, tar, archive

Is it possible to restore a single file from the .tar backup? I don't want to restore total backup. I just want to restore one single file from the backup.

Answer (score 180, accepted):

#### 1. Using the Command-line *tar*

Yes, just give the full stored path of the file after the tarball name.

Example: suppose you want file `etc/apt/sources.list` from `etc.tar`:

```
tar -xf etc.tar etc/apt/sources.list
```

Will extract `sources.list` and create directories `etc/apt` under the current directory.

- You can use the `-t` listing option instead of `-x`, maybe along with *grep*, to find the path of the file you want
- You can also extract a single directory
- *tar* has other options like `--wildcards`, etc. for more advanced partial extraction scenarios; see `man tar`

#### 2. Extract it with the Archive Manager

Open the tar in Archive Manager from Nautilus, go down into the folder hierarchy to find the file you need, and extract it.

- On a server or command-line system, use a text-based file manager such as Midnight Commander (`mc`) to accomplish the same.

#### 3. Using Nautilus/Archive-Mounter

Right-click the tar in Nautilus, and select Open with ArchiveMounter.

The tar will now appear similar to a removable drive on the left, and you can explore/navigate it like a normal drive and drag/copy/paste any file(s) you need to any destination.

Comment: Is there some way to skip the first initial directory. Especially when I don't know the name of it? Like a like wildcard directory.

Comment: Could you tell me if this loads in the entire tar file? Because when I tried to do this for a file (`/etc/network/interfaces`), it worked, but it tool *ages*. I stopped the program but the file was extracted.

Comment: The crucial step for me was to use `the full stored path of the file`. So `./filename` worked, but `filename` don't.

Comment: @ChristopheDeTroyer Tarballs are compressed in such a way that you have to decompress them in full, then take out the file you want. I think that .zip folders are different, so if you want to be able to take out individual files fast, try them.

Comment: Could you add more information on how to do it with Midnight Commander ?

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-extracting-specific-files/