# How to restore downloads folder from de ja dup backup

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I backed up my entire home folder including Downloads.

After purchasing a new laptop, I found there is no "revert to previous version" when right clicking on downloads. There are files in Downloads that I want.

How to access them from my external in De Ja Dup backup?

Comment: Can you please clarify the details. You made a fresh Ubuntu installation on a new backup and then how did you configure DejaDup on the new system? You need to tell DejaDup where your old backups are.

Comment: All other files went back to were they supposed to go, i.e. docs' video and music. All not a problem. I did it individually, using the "revert to" option on every single folder. But with the downloads folder this doesn't exist.

Comment: If you  got a tar pkg then you can do it with this http://askubuntu.com/questions/168795/how-do-i-extract-a-specific-file-from-a-tar-archive

Answer (score 1):

OK, so you have configured DejaDup correctly, because you were able to restore the other folders.

If that is the case, I have probably bad news to you. The default configuration of Deja Dup explicitly excludes the folders Trash and Downloads, as you can see on the following picture:

[image]

Comment: Thanks I know this, but I did an entire system backup and purposely backed Downloads up. So is there no other way to retrieve it without an entire system restore?

Answer (score 1):

You can restore it to specific folder, without infecting your system.
Go to system settings, then backup, klick on restore, select folder where you have your backup, select date of backup, and select 'restore to specific folder' option. It will make folder, where you can find everything, you have previously backuped.

Comment: This does not provide a sufficient answer to the question. Try to add more information, and / or examples.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a solution!
I know its way to late for the original enquirer, but may be it helps some other guys.

So on a fresh install (of the OS or Deja Dup) the folder ~/downloads is ignored. That's why Deja Dup is thinking there is no backup (a little bit stupid, could also show the option and check then...).
So to restore your downloads, you have to remove the folder from the ignored ones. Then Deja Dup thinks there are backups and searches for them.

PS: of course this only helps if there are back ups for this folder :)